How do I debug a segfaulting lua program that imports .so files?
I recently published an application development toolkit written in lua. Here's a link to it: https://github.com/chris-montero/terra
This library was architected from the beginning to support high performance animations. This lua library has some C code that compiles to a few .so files which get imported by the lua code.
When you create a window, and keep resizing it for a while, at a certain point the whole program just segfaults. I get a coredump, but I am unsure how to use gdb (or anything else) to debug this kind of issue. I can't just do gdb -c core.12345 executable because there is no executable.
How can I go about debugging a lua program that imports .so files that segfault at some point?
Here's a link to the github issue, if you want more details: https://github.com/chris-montero/terra/issues/1

There must be an executable ... something is running.  If I understand you correctly then the executable will be the lua interpreter I guess, but if you start GDB then do core-file COREFILE you should see a line like Core was generated by .... which should indicate the executable name, load that as the executable.

@Andrew I did what you said and gdb says "/usr/bin/luajit ./main.lua". I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do now: I tried 'gdb -c ./core.13456 '/usr/bin/luajit ./main.lua', but that doesn't work.

You just need gdb -c ./core.13456 /usr/bin/luajit

I found out how to solve my own issue.

compile your .so files with debug symbols by passing the -g option to gcc (or whatever compiler you use)
open up gdb.
In gdb:

(gdb) set debug jit 1
(gdb) target exec /usr/bin/luajit
(gdb) run ./your_program_name.lua


It would be good to mark your answer as accepted, then folks will know you found a solution that works.
